# Expected expression before > token in template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, instance, raytracing

I'm trying to instantiate a template class inside one of its functions, but for some reason I am unable to do so. It tells gives me the error and points to the beginning of the line, which doesn't make sense.

```
template<typename O>
class ray{

...

color<O> ray_color(const ray<O>& ray, const hittable_list<O>& world, O t_Min, O t_Max, int depth){

    hit_record<O> rec;
    if (world.hit(ray, t_Min, t_Max, rec)){
          Vec3<O> target = rec.p + rec.normal + Vec3<O>::random_in_unit_sphere();
          ray<O> new_ray(rec.p, (target - rec.p));  //line where it fails
          ray.direction() = target - rec.p;
          return ray_color(new_ray, world, t_Min, t_Max, depth-1) * 0.5;
    }
```

It gives me this error:

```
Ray.h: In member function ‘color ray::ray_color(const ray&, const hittable_list&, O, O, int)’:
Ray.h:61:16: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
ray<O> new_ray(rec.p, (target - rec.p));
     ^
```

Which also causes new_array to not be declared and gives subsequent errors.

I have created ray objects elsewhere with the same syntax but only this one gives me an error. What gives?

Note: I know class functions should be implemented in a separate cpp file. I'm planning to do all cleanups like that after I get my program working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your parameters is named `ray`, so in the function body any references to `ray` refer to that parameter, not the class name the function is defined in.

The solution is simple: call your parameter something else.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the issue. I thought it shouldn't matter if I provided the template and constructor values, though. Does the compiler just stop once it sees ray and not make a differentiation?